# Proving this by quadratic function

Tags: inequality, quadratics

> Given are $x$, $y$ and $z\ge0$, if $x^2+y^2+z^2+2xyz=1$, show that
> \[x+y+z\le\dfrac32.\]
> I want to solve this by quadratic function.

Let $x+y+z=k$, so $z=k-x-y$. Plug in and expand to have
\[-2 x {{y}^{2}}+2 {{y}^{2}}-2 {{x}^{2}} y+2 k x y+2 x y-2 k y+2 {{x}^{2}}-2 k x+{{k}^{2}}-1=0.\]
See this as a quadratic function of $y$, so $\Delta\ge0$, which implies that
\begin{align}4 {{x}^{4}}-8 k {{x}^{3}}+8 {{x}^{3}}+4 {{k}^{2}} {{x}^{2}}-12 {{x}^{2}}+8 k x-8 x-4 {{k}^{2}}+8\ge0.\tag{1}\end{align}
We need to find the minimum of $k$, so that $\exists~x$ for $(1)$ to be true. When $k=\dfrac32$,
\[4 {{x}^{4}}-4 {{x}^{3}}-3 {{x}^{2}}+4 x-1=0\implies\left[ x=1\operatorname{,}x=-1\operatorname{,}x=\frac{1}{2}\right]\]
are all *solution*s of $\Delta=0$. How to prove $k\ge\dfrac32$ don't work?

Comment: @RiverLi The inequality sign was reversed. I think it is correct now.

Comment: Yes, it it true.

Comment: The condition is $x, y, z \ge 0$. If the condition is: $x, y$ are real numbers, and $z \ge 0$, the inequality is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = 1$, clearly the desired inequality is true.

In the following, assume that $x < 1$.

Proceeding along OP's approach,
we have
$$\Delta = 4(1-x^2)[3 - 2k -(x-k+1)^2] \ge 0$$
which results in
$k \le 3/2.$

Answer (score 0):

By using our condition and C-S we obtain:
$$2=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+yz}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{x^2+xyz}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+xyz)}=$$
$$=\tfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+\frac{3}{2}(1-x^2-y^2-z^2)}=\tfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq\tfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{6}(x+y+z)^2},$$ which gives $$3-\frac{1}{3}(x+y+z)^2\geq(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$x+y+z\leq\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: Nice. There is a typo after first =.

Comment: @River Li I fixed. Thank you!